# Maximum and minimum for piecewise function

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

I am tasked with finding the exact value for the maximum and minimum of the function

$f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 0 & x \leq 1001  \\ 
\exp(- \frac{1}{(-1001+x)^2(-1003+x)^2}) & 1003 > x > 1001 \\ 
0 & x \geq 1003\end{cases}$

It is fairly easy to see that a minimum is $x = 0$, but as far as I can tell there is no exact value for a maximum. There is however a supremum, but that is not what the question asks.

Am I missing something, or is this question misleading?

Comment: This is a classic construction of a smooth function with compact support (although the smoothness takes some work to do). Since it is positive on the middle interval and zero elsewhere, it hast to take its maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a maximum, not just a supremum. The maxmimum is obtained in $x=1002$.

This is because $x=1002$ maximizes $(-1001+x)^2(-1003+x)^2$ on the interval $(1001,1003)$,
and therefore maximizes $\exp(-\frac1{(-1001+x)^2(-1003+x)^2})$.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum occurs at the minimum of the fraction (minus sign omitted), which occurs at the maximum of the denominator, which occurs at the maximum of the product $|(-1001+x)(-1003+x)|$, which occurs at $1002$.